# How to install Go programming application from a downloaded source code

Tags: go, installation, build

It has been few hours now without any success.... I am trying to install an application "Siegfried".
I have a Redhat server without any internet access why I cannot run wget or brew or anything like as

```
wget -qO - https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/siegfried/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install siegfried
```

I downloaded the source code from

```
https://github.com/richardlehane/siegfried
```

I thought I could build and install... easy as pie.

I realized according to instructions in this page, I need Go programming compiler

```
https://github.com/richardlehane/siegfried/wiki/Getting-started
```

I downloaded Go and fixed the $PATH and Go is working. Now what? I have downloaded the source, I have Go, and now I need to, I guess build, or install or... first build then install. I am going nuts here. How do i proceed? Many thanks for any advices.

ADDING:
Now I have settings i .profile which gives me following:

```
[madde@m101010 etc]$ echo $PATH
/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/arkiv/bin:/opt/pupal/go/bin:/usr/local/arkiv/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin:/usr/local/tomcat9:/usr/local/go/bin:/bin:/home/madde/go/bin
[madde@m101010 etc]$ echo $GOPATH
/home/madde/go
[madde@m101010 etc]$ go version
go version go1.18.2 linux/amd64
```

Still get:

```
[madde@m101010 siegfried-main]$ go install ./cmd/sf
go: github.com/richardlehane/characterize@v1.0.0: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/richardlehane/characterize/@v/v1.0.0.mod: 403 Forbidden
go: downloading github.com/richardlehane/characterize v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/richardlehane/webarchive v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/richardlehane/mscfb v1.0.4
go: downloading github.com/richardlehane/match v1.0.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20211028202545-6944b10bf410
go: downloading github.com/richardlehane/xmldetect v1.0.2
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220114195835-da31bd327af9
go: downloading github.com/ross-spencer/wikiprov v0.2.0
go: github.com/richardlehane/characterize@v1.0.0: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/richardlehane/characterize/@v/v1.0.0.mod: 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: Hmm, when you say you fixed the `$PATH`, what do you mean by that exactly? Do you mean you added `$GOPATH`, or did you add something like `PATH="${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin"`, or both? Either way: `go build` compiles a binary that you can move to any place in your `$PATH`, and `go install` compiles and _installs_ said binary so it can be executed anywhere

Comment: I menat I did this:  
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin  
But after seeing your comment, I did as following:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
Still not working

Answer (score 2):

using `git clone (your link for repo/package you want)`
but you must check in your or move to folder `$GOPATH`

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad
I have now following -- 

[madde@m101010 etc]$ echo $PATH
/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/arkiv/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin:/usr/local/tomcat9:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/arkiv/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin:/usr/local/tomcat9:/usr/local/go/bin:/bin:/home/u0070939/go/bin
 -- 
[madde@m101010 etc]$ echo $GOPATH
/home/u0070939/go
 -- 
[madde@m101010 etc]$ go version
go version go1.18.2 linux/amd64

Comment: `git clone` doesn't build or install go packages. And you don't need it in your `GOPATH`; in fact, you're better of with it outside.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [go install](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) command.

```
go install [build flags] [packages]
```

I followed these steps, and it installed just fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/richardlehane/siegfried.git
cd siegfried
go install ./cmd/sf
go install ./cmd/roy

➜ which sf
/Users/h4s/projects/go/bin/sf

➜ which roy
/Users/h4s/projects/go/bin/roy
```

Comment: Thank you @theherk
It looks as things happens when I try